Converting CD Kickstart file to USB
I have a custom RHEL7 installation ISO, which was created by copying the files out of a downloaded RHEL7 ISO and adding a number of custom kickstart and other files. The goal being to create a single disk with which to install a number of different RHEL configurations (each from a separate kickstart file). When this ISO is burned to a DVD, then everything works fine. Now however I'd like to be able to perform the same installation from a USB device.
Update #1 - The Core Question
I believe that my current problem related to the Installation Source specified in the kickstart file. The original is configured to allow for CD/DVD based install (cdrom is listed as the Installation Source and that works perfectly fine when the ISO is put on a DVD and installed that way), however that doesn't want to work when I put the ISO on a USB drive. Based on what I've seen online, it should be as simple as switching cdrom to harddrive --partition=LABEL=<USB LABEL> --dir=/, however when I do that the installer doesn't find the Installation Source and requires me to input a remote repository to continue.
Update #2 - Progress
So after some more digging I realized that for some reason the .discinfo and .treeinfo files weren't copied over. I've manually copied them over and that seems to have helped (even though they don't appear to be necessary for DVD installation?). I've also added some additional lines to the kickstart file, namely:

Before including the install command I added a manual repository definition repo --name="USB Media" --baseurl=file:///mnt/install/repo
Switched away from nochroot in the %post and instead using a means of finding and mounting the USB device that I encountered elsewhere

usbblkid=$(blkid -L "MY_USB_LABEL")
mount $usbblkid /media/dvd

With these changes I'm seeing some improvements, however it's still not working the way I would expect. What I'm seeing now is:

On every boot from the USB device the Installation Source is displaying the error Error Setting Up Base Repository.
When selecting the repository configuration, there's a roughly 50% chance that

it'll list an option for Auto-Detected Installation Media with the USB listed. I can select the Verify button and it confirms that the media is good to be used. No Additional Repositories are listed. Selecting Done allows the installation to proceed and everything now will work as expected.
the USB Media repository will be listed and selected in the Additional Repositories list. However, the Auto-Detected Installation Media doesn't appear at all. The only source option available is network and I cannot leave this page and return to the main menu without adding something into the URL.


If I am able to proceed past the above, then the installation completes successfully and appears to work exactly as desired.

I am not making any changes to the installation media between attempts, simply selecting Quit and rebooting after accessing the Installation Source from the main page. I would at bare minimum expect that it will consistently do the same thing on every boot, but if it auto-detects the USB installation media I would also expect it to "accept it" automatically and start the installation (same as what happens with the DVD based install). Any thoughts on what might be happening here?
Update #3 - More Progress
Switching to a more elaborate append in the isolinux.cfg looks to have resolved the issue with the Auto-Detected Installation Media not appearing. This line now looks like:
append xdriver=vesa nomodeset initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL inst.repo=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/ inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/config/opt1/anaconda-ks-option1.cfg

With this change I haven't seen a repeat of the Auto-Detected Installation Media not appearing, however on every boot from the USB device the Installation Source is still displaying the error Error Setting Up Base Repository and I have to go into the Installation Source section to "accept" the USB device as the installation source.
For context, the full details of what I'm doing is below.
DVD Installation
First off, to allow for the different kickstart files to be selected there is a custom boot option for each kickstart file in isolinux/isolinux.cfg:
label linux
  menu label Option 1
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append xdriver=vesa nomodeset initrd=initrd.img ks=cdrom:/config/opt1/anaconda-ks-option1.cfg

One entry for each of the kickstart files provided. That allows triggering the separate kickstart files, with each one having the following setup:
firewall --disabled
install
user --name=username --password=password
cdrom
rootpw ==iscrypted password
# additional options

%pre --log=/root/ks-pre.log
# Executes scripts on the DVD to determine target HDD and other such things
sh /mnt/install/repo/config/common/do_stuff.sh
%end

%post --log=/root/ks-post.log
mkdir -p /media/dvd
mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /media/dvd
# Copy files from the DVD and execute various scripts
umount /media/dvd
rmdir /media/dvd
eject /dev/sr0
%end

%packages
# list all required packages
%end

This setup has been working well for us for years, but I'm trying to add support for using a USB installation medium.
USB Installation
This is largely the same as above, just customized to reflect a USB (HDD) source rather than DVD. isolinux/isolinux.cfg is update to reflect a HD source.
label linux
  menu label Option 1
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append xdriver=vesa nomodeset initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL inst.repo=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/ inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/config/opt1/anaconda-ks-option1.cfg

where the ISO I generate is given the label MY_USB_LABEL. The kickstart files are left unchanged, except for again changing the reference from DVD to HDD:
firewall --disabled
repo --name="USB Media" --baseurl=file:///mnt/install/repo # ADDED
install
harddrive --partition=LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL --dir=/ # replaces the cdrom option
user --name=username --password=password
rootpw ==iscrypted password
# additional options

%pre --log=/root/ks-pre.log
# Executes scripts on the DVD to determine target HDD and other such things
# NO CHANGE HERE!
sh /mnt/install/repo/config/common/do_stuff.sh
%end

%post --log=/root/ks-post.log
mkdir -p /media/dvd

usbblkid=$(blkid -L "MY_USB_LABEL") # Change which device is mounted
mount $usbblkid /media/dvd # Change which device is mounted

#mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /media/dvd
cd /media/dvd

# Everything else left unchanged after this point
%end

%packages
# list all required packages
# NO CHANGE HERE!
%end

So to summarize, the only changes I've made are in:

isolinux/isolinux.cfg - change ks=cdrom:/ to append xdriver=vesa nomodeset initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL inst.repo=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/ inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/config/opt1/anaconda-ks-option1.cfg
kickstart - added a manual reference to the Repository located on the USB
kickstart - change cdrom installation source to harddrive --partition=LABEL=<USB LABEL> --dir=/
kickstart - the post section is (now) largely unchanged, with the only differnce being how which device is mounted. Using usbblkid to find the USB device and then mounting it.

So with all this said and done, I can see that the kickstart is triggered however it's failing to resolve the Installation Source. If I select it in the installer, it doesn't even show the USB as a viable source, giving me only the option for using something remote. Local Media or equivalent is not available. In my situation I want to rely on the local media, as our target system(s) are offline and we cannot rely on some form of remote repository being available.
In case it is of interest, I'm generating/preparing the ISO/USB by running the following commands:
mkisofs -quiet -o test.iso -V MY_USB_LABEL \
        -R -J -joliet-long -l -T \
        -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \
        -no-emul-boot \
        -boot-load-size 4 \
        -boot-info-table \
        -eltorito-alt-boot \
        -e images/efiboot.img \
        -no-emul-boot \
        -graft-points iso_dir/
isohybrid -u test.iso
implantisomd5 test.iso
dd if=test.iso of=/dev/sda && sync

Note: I'm focusing first on getting the legacy boot working before turning my attention to EFI. I'm assuming that the only change will be updating the inst.ks=cdrom entry EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg in an equivalent manner (inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL).

This question is similar to: Red Hat 7.4: How to inject kickstart file into USB media for UEFI-only system?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  I do note that the OP said non-UEFI but I believe this will put the OP on the right track.

Thanks for that link! I don't think I'd seen that one yet, and it's definitely very informative, however it doesn't really talk about how the kickstart file needs to differ from CD to USB (simply leaving it as the "CD version" doesn't work for me). Specifically for the installation source. I'll update my question to make this clearer.

I've made some progress, in that seems that some files (.discinfo and .treeinfo) were missing. Beyond that though, it's still not either behaving consistently nor how I would expect. Updated the main question with the full details (See Update #2).

Some more progress... it appears that a more elaborate isolinux.cfg append line resolves one of the issues (namely with the USB not always being detected as the installation media on boot).
